# Gradle unable to find android_native_app_glue

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a native library which I am trying to build with gradle. If I invoke the ndk-build command from the gradle file, I am able to build the native library. But if I try to use the ndk build functionality built in the android gradle plugin I an unable to build.

I get `fatal error: android_native_app_glue.h: No such file or directory`

The relevant section of the gradle file is:

```
buildTypes.debug.jniDebugBuild true

defaultConfig {
    ndk {
      moduleName 'myModule'
      stl 'gnustl_static'
      cFlags '-UNDEBUG -Werror -Wunused-variable -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wtype-limits -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wreturn-type -Wuninitialized'
      ldLibs 'log', 'GLESv2'
    }
    productFlavors {
      armv7{
        ndk {
          abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the ndk build where to find the android_native_app_glue.h file?

On a side note, is there a way to pass the verbose flag to ndk-build, the equivalent of `ndk-build V=1` ?

Comment: what's your minSdkVersion ? it needs to be at least 9 for this project if you want to use android_native_app_glue.h `ldLibs 'android'` may also be needed.

Comment: Do you have an android_native_app_glue.h file and what directory did you put it in?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding
 `"-I{path_to_android-ndk}/sources/android/native_app_glue"` 
to cFlags, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76822)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add it to your LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in Android.mk, like this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /path/to/ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue
```

Make sure the path is correct, by doing an `ls` on `/path/to/ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue/native_app_glue.h`

Answer (score 0):

As of:

- gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha2
- gradle-2.9-all.zip

One way to do it (Or to integrate any code that can be compiled and link as a static library) is to create in your project a new module, and change the gradle file of that module to be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "0.0.1"
        }
        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native-activity"
        cppFlags.add("-Werror")
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "android"])
        stl        = "gnustl_static"
        ldFlags.add("-c")
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir "${ndkDir}/sources/android/native_app_glue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your module's gradle.mk you should just add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')

model {
    android {
        [...]
    }
    android.ndk {
        [...]

        cppFlags.add("-I${file("${ndkDir}/sources/android/native_app_glue")}".toString())
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    project ":native-activity" linkage "static"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':native-activity')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these line in your `cMakeList.txt` file

```
//line1
include_directories(${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)

//line2
add_library(native_app_glue STATIC
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)
```

also add `native_app_glue` in `target_link_libraries`.

It come in effect only after click on **RUN** or **shift + F10**

Answer (score 0):

Add to cmake

```
include(AndroidNdkModules)
android_ndk_import_module_native_app_glue()

target_link_libraries(
        native_app_glue
)
```